# Feature selection not working in SVR with rbf kernel for n_features_to_select = 0.25 (anything below 1)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, gridsearchcv, rfe

I have a dataset with the following dimension (x_train, y_train) :-

**type** : numpy.ndarray
**dimension**: x_train: (3618, 1425) and y_train : (3618,)
** sklearn version** : 0.24.1

I am trying to fit a Support Vector regression.
The code is as follows :

```
folds = KFold(n_splits = 5, shuffle = True, random_state = 100)

# specify range of hyperparameters
hyper_params = [{
                "n_features_to_select": [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0],
                "estimator__C" : [1000, 100 ],
                "estimator__epsilon" : [0.1, 0.001, 0]}]

# specify model
lm = SVR(kernel="rbf", max_iter=10000)
#lm.fit(x_train,y_train)
rfe = RFE(lm)             

# set up GridSearchCV()
model_cv = GridSearchCV(estimator = rfe, 
                        param_grid = hyper_params, 
                        scoring= 'r2', 
                        cv = folds, 
                        verbose = 3,
                        return_train_score=True,
                        refit = True)      

# fit the model
model_cv.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

However, during fit I am getting Nan for both train and test score for `n_features_to_select` 0.25, 0.5 and 0.75 i.e everything that is not 1.0

```
[CV 1/5] END estimator__C=1000, estimator__epsilon=0.1, n_features_to_select=0.75;, score=(train=nan, test=nan) total time=   8.2s
[CV 2/5] END estimator__C=1000, estimator__epsilon=0.1, n_features_to_select=0.75;, score=(train=nan, test=nan) total time=   8.0s
[CV 3/5] END estimator__C=1000, estimator__epsilon=0.1, n_features_to_select=0.75;, score=(train=nan, test=nan) total time=   8.0s
[CV 4/5] END estimator__C=1000, estimator__epsilon=0.1, n_features_to_select=0.75;, score=(train=nan, test=nan) total time=   8.1s
[CV 5/5] END estimator__C=1000, estimator__epsilon=0.1, n_features_to_select=0.75;, score=(train=nan, test=nan) total time=   8.0s
[CV 1/5] END estimator__C=1000, estimator__epsilon=0.1, n_features_to_select=1.0;, score=(train=1.000, test=0.665) total time=  11.0s
[CV 2/5] END estimator__C=1000, estimator__epsilon=0.1, n_features_to_select=1.0;, score=(train=1.000, test=0.666) total time=  11.1s
[CV 3/5] END estimator__C=1000, estimator__epsilon=0.1, n_features_to_select=1.0;, score=(train=1.000, test=0.679) total time=  11.1s
[CV 4/5] END estimator__C=1000, estimator__epsilon=0.1, n_features_to_select=1.0;, score=(train=1.000, test=0.663) total time=  11.1s
[CV 5/5] END estimator__C=1000, estimator__epsilon=0.1, n_features_to_select=1.0;, score=(train=1.000, test=0.632) total time=  11.0s
```

Why is this happening? And how to solve it ?

I tried another regression technique to check namely `LinearRegression` with

```
hyper_params = [{'n_features_to_select': [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]}]
```

It is working perfectly fine.

**Minimal Replicable Toy Dataset**

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np

X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=50, n_features=10, random_state=0)
estimator = SVR(kernel="rbf", max_iter=10000)
selector = RFE(estimator)

# set up GridSearchCV()
folds = KFold(n_splits = 5, shuffle = True, random_state = 100)

param = [{
    "estimator__C" : [1000, 100 ],
    "estimator__epsilon" : [0.1, 0.001, 0],
    "n_features_to_select": [0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0]
}]


gridsearch = GridSearchCV(estimator = selector, 
                        param_grid = param, 
                        scoring= 'r2', 
                        cv = folds, 
                        verbose = 3,
                        return_train_score=True,
                        refit = True)  

selector = gridsearch.fit(X, y)
```

I realised I was suppressing the warning, so adding the warning:

```
ValueError: when `importance_getter=='auto'`, the underlying estimator SVR should have `coef_` or `feature_importances_` attribute. Either pass a fitted estimator to feature selector or call fit before calling transform.

  warnings.warn(some_fits_failed_message, FitFailedWarning)
/home/subora/anaconda3/envs/thesis/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py:969: UserWarning: One or more of the test scores are non-finite: [       nan        nan        nan 0.42252336        nan        nan
        nan 0.42192834        nan        nan        nan 0.42191628
        nan        nan        nan 0.42252336        nan        nan
        nan 0.42192834        nan        nan        nan 0.42191628]
  warnings.warn(
/home/subora/anaconda3/envs/thesis/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py:969: UserWarning: One or more of the train scores are non-finite: [       nan        nan        nan 0.99969375        nan        nan
        nan 0.99999996        nan        nan        nan 1.
        nan        nan        nan 0.99969375        nan        nan
        nan 0.99999996        nan        nan        nan 1.        ]
  warnings.warn(
```

**Edit 2**

Tried changing the kernel to `linear` and it is working fine as the estimator has `coef_`. so what I understood is feature selection only works with linear kernel.

Comment: What version of sklearn are you running? If it's less than v0.24, you can only use whole numbers for RFE

Comment: It is above 0.24 as decimal (0.25, 0.5 and 0.75) is working for LinearRegression

Comment: Not the fraction, the _version_ of sklearn. As in `import sklearn as skl;print(skl.__version__)`

Comment: See in [the RFE documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html) "n_features_to_select: ...Changed in version 0.24: Added float values for fractions."

Comment: @Echo but hard to identify the issue without access to data. Is it possible to share the data ?

Comment: @G.Anderson the version is 0.24.1. what I meant from my comment is that when I used the hyper parameter for Linear regression, it worked fine.

Comment: @mujjiga I have added a toy dataset.

Comment: See also https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/104667/55122

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html) for `importance_getterstr` argument

> **importance_getterstr or callable, default=’auto’** If ‘auto’, uses the
> feature importance either through a coef_ or feature_importances_
> attributes of estimator.

So the feature selector needs the underlining estimator to expose either `coef_` or `feature_importances_` so that the features can be selected.

```
X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=50, n_features=10, random_state=0)

svr = SVR(kernel="rbf")
lr = LinearRegression()
#selector = RFE(estimator, n_features_to_select=5, step=1)
svr = svr.fit(X, y)
lr = lr.fit(X,y)
print (hasattr(svr, "coef_"), hasattr(svr, "feature_importances_"))
print (hasattr(lr, "coef_"), hasattr(lr, "feature_importances_"))
```

Output:

```
False False
True False
```

you can see that the `LinearRegression` exposed `coef_` however `SVR` does not implement either of them. So the feature selector with `SVR` as estimator will fail during feature selection. Note that this errors happens only when feature selection is done i.e when `n_features_to_select != 1.0`. When `n_features_to_select==1.0` all the features will be used and so no feature selection will come into the picture.

```
 RFE(estimator, n_features_to_select=1.0)
```

will not fail but

```
 RFE(estimator, n_features_to_select=0.9)
```

will fail with `SVR` as estimator. For all the cases where it failed, the result is set to `nan` which is clear from the error messages

> 90 fits failed out of a total of 120. The score on these train-test
> partitions for these parameters will be set to nan.

Fixed code:

```
X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=50, n_features=10, random_state=0)
estimator = SVR(kernel="rbf", max_iter=10000)
selector = RFE(estimator)
# set up GridSearchCV()
folds = KFold(n_splits = 5, shuffle = True, random_state = 100)

param = [{
    "estimator__C" : [1000, 100 ],
    "estimator__epsilon" : [0.1, 0.001, 0],
    "n_features_to_select": [1.0]
}]


gridsearch = GridSearchCV(estimator = selector, 
                        param_grid = param, 
                        scoring= 'r2', 
                        cv = folds, 
                        verbose = 3,
                        return_train_score=True,
                        refit = True)  

selector = gridsearch.fit(X, y)
```

If you want to grid search on `n_features_to_select` then you will have to implement a function that returns the feature importance and give that function to the `importance_getter` argument of  `RFE`

Comment: What sis you fix ? Did you just remove the other n_features_to_select ?

Comment: 1. Use an estimator which supports `coef_` or `feature_importances_`. 2. Or use SVR without `n_features_to_select `, 3. Or use SVR and implement a function that returns the feature importance and pass it to `importance_getter`. I just showed "2" way as fix.